# htaccess issues with non existent files in non existent directories

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am using the following `.htaccess` file, which works well, however, I want to also forward any attempts to access non-existent files in the root directory and in any subdirectory (whether the subdirectory exists or not) back to the main domain name.

I tried `FallbackResource` but that resulted in 500 series errors.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|png|css|pdf)$ -     [F]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 401 /redirect
ErrorDocument 403 /redirect
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the error log say?

Comment: 404 errors with entries for css, js and an image with a path with the random directory that doesn't exist. The paths to those includes are relative. That's why I'd rather just forward back to the main site.

Comment: That sounds like the "access log", not the "error log"? You don't normally see 404 HTTP responses (which are not strictly server "errors") in the "error log". "The paths to those includes are relative. That's why I'd rather just forward back to the main site." - not sure what you mean by the first bit about relative paths? Can you give an example of the URL(s) being requested.

Answer (score 0):

`FallbackResource` results in the URL being *internally rewritten* to another file. However, I would have thought an *external redirect* would be preferable in this situation? Also, `FallbackResource` might conflict with your existing mod_rewrite directives. (However, it would have been useful to see your use of `FallbackResource` in-place, as it could have been your syntax that was at fault?)

Try something like the following, after your last mod_rewrite directive (before your `ErrorDocument` directives):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The above says... if the request does not map to a file and does not map to a directory then redirect to the document root (temporary 302). The `QSD` is required to remove any query string from the request.

*Aside:* This is not recommended from an SEO (or users) point of view, if that is a concern.

---

> ```
> ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
> ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
> ErrorDocument 500 /redirect
> ErrorDocument 404 /error
> ErrorDocument 401 /redirect
> ErrorDocument 403 /redirect
> ```

(Apart from unnecessarily defining the 500 error document more than once...) the *document* specified in the `ErrorDocument` directive should be a root-relative *filesystem* path. eg. `/redirect.php` (But that doesn't actually *redirect* does it?) Presumably you don't actually have a file called `/redirect` (that would require further rewriting).

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work, everything just forwards to the main site

Comment: When you say "everything", do you mean existing files/directories also get redirected?

Comment: yes all files/folders

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your folder structure and example URLs you are requesting. I've also updated my answer with regards to your `ErrorDocument` directives.